# How to send different data types from React and receive it on Flask?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

Trying to send user image with user data to create user on backend using flask. Now I send it as params but want to put it all in body in post request on React

React:

```
 const newData = new FormData()
 newData.append('file',image)
 await createArtist({token:token,name:data.name,image:newData})

//In api component

async function createArtist({token,name,image}){
    return await fetch(`/create_artist/${name}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        body: image
    }).then(async (response) => {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        if(!response.ok)
        {
            if(response.status === 401)
                throw new Error(jsonResponse.msg);
            else
                throw new Error('Unknown error ' + response.status);
        }
    });
}
```

Flask:

```
@app.route("/create_artist/<name>",methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
@jwt_required()
def create_artist(name):
    # user_id = get_jwt_identity()

    data = request.files["file"]

    image_bytes = helpers.read_file_bytes(data)

    try:
        utils.create_artist(connection,name,image_bytes)
    except:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Server Error"}), 401
    return jsonify({"msg": "Success"}), 200
```

Instead of just "body: image" want to have smth like "body: {image,name}"

Answer (score -2):

To send different data types from React and receive it on Flask, you can follow these steps:

1. In React, make an HTTP request to your Flask server using a library like Axios or Fetch. Here's an example using Axios:

```
javascript
import axios from 'axios';

const sendDataToFlask = async () => {
  const data = {
    stringData: 'Hello Flask!',
    numberData: 42,
    booleanData: true,
    arrayData: [1, 2, 3],
    objectData: { key: 'value' },
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/your-flask-endpoint', data);
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

2. In your Flask server, define a route that can receive the data. Here's an example using Flask's `request` module:

```
python
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/your-flask-endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    # Process the received data as needed
    # ...

    return 'Data received successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In this example, the received data is printed on the server-side. You can modify the server code to process the data according to your requirements.

Make sure to replace `/your-flask-endpoint` with the actual endpoint URL on your Flask server.

Remember to install Axios in your React project (`npm install axios`) and Flask (`pip install flask`) on your server if you haven't already.